# How to make a UI for a checkers game with gtkmm?

Tags: c++, user-interface, gtk, gtkmm

I made a checkers game in C++ with a console UI and I'd like to make it more user-friendly.
I've started looking into Gtkmm to make a UI.

In my model, the board is represented as a 10*10 array of Pieces.
A move is represented as a starting coordinate and an ending coordinate.

First of all, I'd like to be able to draw the board that I have in my model with Gtkmm.
In order to make a move, I want the user to first click on the piece he wants to move, and then on the spot he wants the piece to arrive.
If that move is correct, the board will have to be drawn again (the piece will be moved, and some of the opponent pieces might be destroyed).

Thanks to this tutorial : https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/ , I'm now able to make a grid and fill it with widgets (e.g. buttons).
I've already made a grid and filled it with buttons.
When a button is clicked, I can get the coordinate.

Here's my question : In order to make the UI that I described, what should I fill my grid with ? Should I stick with buttons ?
Should I use drag & drop ?
How should I proceed in order to make this UI ? I'm kind of lost… (this is my first time making an event-oriented UI…).

Comment: whats your aim in this, making a game or learning gtkmm?

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly. Both I guess.

Comment: better use something like open gl/ogre/unity/osg for making games. afaik there are extensions to use them inside gtkmm

Comment: You could just base your widget on a GtkWidget and make it all custom, handling everything yourself.